# Typescript NuGets: compiler vs msbuild

Tags: msbuild, typescript, visual-studio-2015, nuget

There are two NuGets offered by Microsoft for Typescript.

- [Compiler](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TypeScript.Compiler/)
- [MsBuild](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild/)

I have a visual studio project that I want to run on an old build machine that does not have a current Typescript installed (It is running TFS Build 2010).

But I need to build my project with a new version of Typescript.

Do I need the compiler or msbuild nuget?  (Or are neither of them going to work for what I need?)

Update: I tried the MsBuild version and it took my working project and broke it.  I got a ton of compiler errors.  (`Cannot find name....` errors).

Comment: did you solve your Problem?

Comment: @squadwuschel - I don't recall for sure, but I think I solved it by doing something completely different.